# Problema con posible macro excel vb

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy trabajando con montones de ficheros txt y necesito una macro excel que me haga lo siguiente (si es posible).

os lo detallo: Tengo una ruta con distintos .txt con nombres distintos, esto es un ejemplo

> prueba1.txt
>
> prueba2.txt
>
> prueba3.txt
>
> prueba4.txt
>
> prueba5.txt

Necesito una macro que exporte a excel el nombre de cada fichero txt y abra cada fichero y lea sus lineas y ponga la cantidad de lineas por txt algo tal que así:

> NOMBRE FICHERO TXT ///// LINEAS
>
> prueba1.txt //// 5
>
> prueba2.txt //// 4000
>
> prueba3.txt //// 22541
>
> prueba4.txt //// 19874
>
> prueba5.txt //// 44457

¿Alguien que me ayude a sacar esto?

Comment: Hola Sergio y bienvenido. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Puedes compartir el código que ya tengas hecho? Es importante que lo intentes antes de preguntar para aportar algo de código :).

Comment: la verdad es que yo de programación ando muy pez y he entrado aquí por recomendación de un compañero de trabajo que trabaja en desarrollo java

Comment: Mírate el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)... No tengo claro que una pregunta así sea válida para el sitio.

Comment: Por favor, no encuentro información en internet sobre el tema y que me pueda servir, y no conozco a nadie que sepa de vb y macros en excel para poderlo realizar.

Comment: Sergio, en internet tienes muchísimos tutoriales al respecto. Además, no te has tomado la molestia en leerte el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) que ya te había comentado. Tu pregunta no se adapta al sitio. Busca tutoriales (http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html), crea macros, intenta hacerlo y si tienes problemas, vuelve aquí y te ayudaremos sin ningún problema.

Comment: igualmente gracias, ya me han ayudado en otro sitio.

Comment: Dim h As Worksheet
    Set h = Sheets("Hoja1")
        Dim fs, f, f1, fc, s, sFldr, folderspec
        folderspec = "C:\carpeta\"
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderspec)
        Set fc = f.SubFolders
        Set fc = f.Files
        x = 1
        For Each f1 In fc
            f2 = Replace(f1, folderspec, "")
            Set theFile = fso.OpenTextFile(f1, 8, True)
            h.Cells(x, 1).Value = f2 & "\\\" & theFile.Line
            x = x + 1

Comment: Sergio, si quieres puedes responder a tu propia pregunta con el código que comentas.

Comment: Hola chicos, ahora después de todo esto, nos surge la duda de... necesitamos sacar del nombre que nos saca el código, necesitamos que de ese nombre nos extraiga ciertos caracteres, por ejemplo del nombre 12345_CONTRATOS_67-896-04_MFID queremos que nos extraiga la cadena 67-896-04, alguien sabe?

Answer (score 2):

El codigo para esto es el siguiente.
Gracias al forero [Zero Racing](http://www.forocoches.com/foro/member.php?u=570351) de Forocoches

```
Sub ShowFolderList()
Dim h As Worksheet
Set h = Sheets("Hoja1")
    Dim fs, f, f1, fc, s, sFldr, folderspec
    folderspec = "C:\carpeta\"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderspec)
    Set fc = f.SubFolders
    Set fc = f.Files
    x = 1
    For Each f1 In fc
        f2 = Replace(f1, folderspec, "")
        Set theFile = fso.OpenTextFile(f1, 8, True)
        h.Cells(x, 1).Value = f2 & "\\\" & theFile.Line
        x = x + 1
    Next
End Sub
```